# Search for a string in the whole Excel Workbook

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, search

How can I find all the occurences of a sequence of characters in the **whole Excel workbook** ? (Excel search is limited to the current sheet only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the find box, hit options to search the whole workbook.

[image]